# Div overlaps when resized vertically

Tags: html, css

When trying to resize my webpage horizontally everything works out fine. When I try to resize the page vertically the divs start overlapping and the whole webpage looks weird. What could I try to fix this?

```css
    .container-1-wrapper
    {
      width:100vw;
      height:100vh;
      background: #3399FF;
    
    }
    .container-2-wrapper
    {
      width:100vw;
      height:100vh;
      background:   #f9f9eb;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container-1-wrapper"></div>
<div class="container-2-wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: could you please provide more code? this is just css, we need more information to answer your question

Comment: How does it overlap weird? ... Add more info on what it does and how it should, as in its present state it is very unclear what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend adding this to your styling on that section:

```
.container-1-wrapper
{
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  background: #3399FF;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

This will put your code in a block format that's relative to the content surrounding it as well as clearing any text/elements on both sides of the page. I highly recommend this if you can (or are able to) float your elements to one side. If you code a float into your elements, this will keep your divs from running into each other. It should clear out both sides of the div element.

Also, if you're attempting to resize your page to format to another device, maybe this code snippet will help you out:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Put this at the beginning of your CSS right under the declaration of font type and such (in the section for metadata). This should make your page so that it always scales up and down with the size of your window.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: Not sure how this answer got 2 upvotes, as it does nothing to OP's sample code. E.g. `display: block` is the default value for a `div`, so what you mean saying it makes a _"block format that is relative to the surrounding"_ makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

With the little information you can only guess:

Try to apply a `position: relative` and `display: block` to the wrapper